# Laravel project is not being copied to the Docker container

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose

When I am creating a docker container using the configuration, then in my container, I want to copy my already existing project to the docker container in `/var/www/html` directory. But my workdir seems to be empty.

Here, I'm attaching my Dockerfile and docker-composer.ymk

Dockerfile

```
FROM php:8.1.0-apache
WORKDIR /var/www/html

# Mode Rewrite
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Linux Library
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y \
    libicu-dev \
    libmariadb-dev \
    unzip zip \
    zlib1g-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libjpeg-dev \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libpng-dev

# Composer
COPY --from=composer:latest /usr/bin/composer /usr/bin/composer

# PHP Extension
RUN docker-php-ext-install gettext intl pdo_mysql gd

RUN docker-php-ext-configure gd --enable-gd --with-freetype --with-jpeg \
    && docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:

  laravel-docker:
    container_name: laravel-docker
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./laravel-app:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - 9000:80

  mysql-db:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: laravel-app
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  phpmyadmin:
    image: phpmyadmin:latest
    ports:
      - 9001:80
    environment:
      - PMA_ARBITRARY=1
```

Comment: so, you go inside your container like this `docker compose exec laravel-docker bash` and you should already be inside `/var/www/html` and if you do `ls -lah` you see `.` and `..` and nothing else? Share what you see

Comment: Exactly @matiaslauriti

Comment: Then, are you sure you have data in `laravel-app` folder? Can you share that? Also, is your `docker-compose.yml` file in the same folder where you also have `laravel-app` folder?